# How to concat date values to one string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date values like these '2019.10.13' in table but I want to represent it as a single string like this '20191013'.
How can I do this if I have to use just the functions like substr,instr ?
I tried doing this
select concat(concat(substring(date,1,4),substring(date,6,7)),substring(date,9,10))
but it gave results like this -

> 202006.0202

The 'dd' part being concatenated twice.

Comment: `REPLACE('2019.10.13', '.', '')`, perhaps?

Comment: @esqew, no need for a replacement character?

Comment: @jarlh Good catch, thanks - still early for me here. ;)

Comment: @esqew, the no 1 rule is no SQL before coffee!

Answer (score 2):

Don’t bother with anything more complex than you need; use `REPLACE` to swap all full stop characters with a blank string:

```
REPLACE('2019.10.13', '.', '')
```